# Validate the claim that it is better to use pointers to pointers while working with binary trees

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree, cs50

[In this video (a section/recitation for an online course called CS50)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfBASB1RCOQ&t=60m0s), around 1h00m00s, the student instructor goes into pointers-to-pointers and why it is <strike>more efficient</strike> **useful** to implement insert on the binary tree this way.  At least, that is what I'm getting from the argument.

I did a recursive implementation both ways.  I don't see why Option A is better than Option B in the below...perhaps you could help me reason this out or point me in the right direction if I'm misunderstood?

## Option A (with pointers-to-pointers)

```
bool insert(int value, node* tree)
    {
        node** tmptree = &tree;
        // make sure the tree itself isn't null
        if(*tmptree != NULL)
        {
            if(value == (*tmptree)->value)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if(value < (*tmptree)->value)
            {
                tmptree = &(*tmptree)->left;
                // we must be at a null leaf!
                if(*tmptree == NULL)
                {
                    // make sure we built a leaf
                    *tmptree = build_node(value);
                    if(*tmptree == NULL)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return insert(value, *tmptree);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                tmptree = &(*tmptree)->right;
                if(*tmptree == NULL)
                {
                    *tmptree = build_node(value);
                    if(*tmptree == NULL)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return insert(value, *tmptree);
                }
            }
        }
        return false; // if the tree is null
    }
```

## Option B (regular ptrs)

```
    bool insert(int value, node* tree)
    {
        if(tree != NULL)
        {
            if(value == tree->value)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if(value < tree->value)
            {
                if(tree->left == NULL)
                {
                    node* tmp = build_node(value);
                    if(tmp != NULL)
                    {
                        tree->left = tmp;
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return insert(value, tree->left);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(tree->right == NULL)
                {
                    node* tmp = build_node(value);
                    if(tmp != NULL)
                    {
                        tree->right = tmp;
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return insert(value, tree->right);
                }
            }
        }
        return false; // if the tree is null
    }
```

The build_node function:

```
    node* build_node(int value)
    {
        node* node = malloc(sizeof( node ));
        if(node == NULL)
            return NULL;
        node->value = value;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;
        return node;
    }
```

Comment: Your second implementation doesn't work at all.

Comment: Where are you seeing the problem?

Comment: When a value is passed as an argument in C, it is copied.  So doing `node **tmptree = &tree;` is useless because it refers to the copy, not the original tree.  So when you use the function `*tmptree = build_node (value);` that modifies your copy, but it doesn't add anything to the tree.  If you want to use regular pointers, then you need to implement it in the *functional* style.

Comment: What's even better is using indentation!

Comment: More precisely, both A and B are wrong. A pointer to pointer point to local pointer is quite pointless in this case.

Comment: @moeCake It's pointless! lol

Comment: My apologies @Bit Fiddling Code Monkey, the code should read easily now.

Comment: If you still not understand, put pointer to pointer as function argument, is to let sub function actually manipulate pointer from caller. It's just a pointer version of passed by address, thus `node** tmptree = &tree;` is not going to work as intend.

Comment: @ironicaldiction Thanks.  It makes people more likely to read it.

Comment: I think I understand you, @moeCake and @randomusername.  The instructor was simply trying to illustrate--via Option A--that you can directly access the parent and children nodes without using the struct attributres `left` and `right` by using double pointers.  He is not trying to use the original memory passed into the function, however.

Comment: In reply to your next comment, @moeCake, the intent was _not_ to manipulate the original memory, in other words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have misunderstood why there is a pointer-to-pointer in the original code. The "Option a" doesn't make any sense, there is no advantage of using pointer-to-pointer just for the sake of it.

The only reason you would use pointer-to-pointer is because you want to change the pointed-to address and return it to the caller.

For example

```
void func (int** ptr)
{
  *ptr = something;
}

func(&my_ptr);

// is the very thing same as

int* func (int* ptr)
{
  return something;
}

my_ptr = func(my_ptr);
```

You can't use the second version and type `ptr = something` inside the function, because `ptr` is a local variable and will cease to exist once you leave the function. Assigning something to it won't affect the original pointer at the caller's side.

The only advantage of the pointer-to-pointer version is that the returned type can be used for something else, like for example returning an error code.

And that seems to be exactly why the guy in that video used it. His function looks like

```
bool insert (int value, node** tree);
```

where the `*tree` is assigned to point at another address from inside the function and the bool is used as a status code, when he reaches the end of a tree branch.

Comment: I think you're exactly correct.  I re-watched the portion of the video I was stuck on, and the reason the student passes in a `node**` is to change the tree's composition if the pointer to the node pointer is `NULL`.  This way, if someone passes in `&root` where `node* root = NULL;`, the tree can just make the inserted value the root `node*`, which is the expected behavior of insert on a binary tree.